# multiTooltipTemplate in Chart.js 2.0

Tags: chart.js

I'm using Chart.js 2.0 in my project.

I want change tooltip template for my line chart. By default `Chart.defaults.global.multiTooltipTemplate = "<%if (datasetLabel){%><%=datasetLabel%>: <%}%><%= value %>"`. But after changing `multiTooltipTemplate`'s value to `"<%= value %>"` tooltip is not updated.

So what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. Simply use `Chart.defaults.global.tooltips.callbacks.label = function(t, e) { return t.ylabel; }`